# What's the difference between these two methods for calculating a weighted median?

Tags: median, weighted

I'm trying to calculate a weighted median, but don't understand the difference between the following two methods. The answer I get from weighted.median() is different from (df, median(rep(value, count))), but I don't understand why. Are there many ways to get a weighted median? Is one more preferable over the other?

```
df = read.table(text="row  count value

1             1.                      25.
2             2.                      26.
3             3.                      30.
4             2.                      32.
5             1.                      39.", header=TRUE)


# weighted median
with(df, median(rep(value, count)))
# [1] 30

library(spatstat)
weighted.median(df$value, df$count)
# [1] 28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `with(df, median(rep(value, count)))` only makes sense for weights which are positive integers (`rep` will accept float values for `count` but will coerce them to integers). This approach is thus not a full general approach to computing weighted medians. `?weighted.median` shows that what the function tries to do is to compute a value `m` such that the total weight of the data below `m` is 50% of the total weight. In the case of your sample, there is no such `m` that works exactly. 28.5% of the total weight of the data is <= 26 and 61.9% is <= 30. In a case like this, by default ("type 2") it averages these 2 values to get the 28 that is returned. There are two other types. `weighted.median(df$value,df$count,type = 1)` returns 30. I am not completely sure if this type will always agree with your other approach.

Comment: Also, you mean 28, right?

Comment: @Nate Yes, that was a typo. Thanks.